# Cue different Javascript/JQuery revents as window resizes below/above a set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, resize, window

I'm trying to set up a JavaScript + JQuery to change some elements' positions if the browser window is resized past a certain width (800px) in either direction.

There are three states:

1. Browser width > 800px, menu open
2. Browser width <= 800px, menu closed
3. Browser width <= 800px, menu open

The menu Open/Close operation is handled by an onClick event for divs that are hidden when the browser width exceeds 800px (#menushow and #menuhide).

What I need is for the menu options to reset to State 1 is the browser is resized to above 800px in width, and State 2 if the browser is resized to below 800px in width.

The menu elements consist of a < nav id="access" > element, and the decorative < div id="sibebar-bottom" > element.

The code I have at the moment is this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {  
if ( $(window).width() > 800){ 
    document.getElementById('menushow').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('menuhide').style.display = "none";
    $( "#sidebar-bottom" ).removeClass('closemenu')
    $( "#sidebar-bottom" ).addClass('openmenu')
    $( "#sidebar-bottom" ).animate({top: "570px"}, 300, 'easeOutExpo')
    $( "#access" ).animate({top: "0px"}, 300, 'easeOutExpo')  
} 
if ( $(window).width() <= 800 ){ 
    document.getElementById('menushow').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('menuhide').style.display = "none";
    $( "#sidebar-bottom" ).removeClass('closemenu')
    $( "#sidebar-bottom" ).addClass('openmenu')
    $( "#sidebar-bottom" ).animate({top: "103px"}, 300, 'easeOutExpo')
    $( "#access" ).animate({top: "-477px"}, 300, 'easeOutExpo')  
} 

}
```

However, when I resize the window from >800px to smaller, nothing moves. And if I resize from <800px to >800px, I get an animation loop that hides and shows the menu repeatedly.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to use media queries and CSS3? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

Comment: You say there are three states but only describe the first 2.

Comment: Hi TheZ, there are media queries in place, yes. But they get overridden if the browser has been resized AFTER JavaScript has acted on the menu objects. The JavaScript is there to expand a minimised UI on tablet devices, to give more real estate to the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement has a condition of **greater than** or equal to 800, I assume that's supposed to be **less than** or equal to 800.

Comment: Oh wow. I was expecting to discover I'd used an entirely inappropriate syntax method… not a typo!   If that's all that's wrong with it, then thank you for your help and sorry for wasting your time!!!